# Using two phase commits on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, two-phase-commit

Assuming that a have a table called "t1" in a "db1" and other table called "t2" in a "db2", and I need to insert a record on both tables or fails.

Connected to db1, I guess I shall type this:

```
BEGIN;
PREPARE TRANSACTION 'pepe'; -- this says the manual that makes your transaction gets stored on disk, so what is the purpose if I can't use it from another database?)

insert into t1 (field) values ('a_value');

COMMIT PREPARED 'pepe'
```

Connected to db2, I guess that:

```
BEGIN;
PREPARE TRANSACTION 'pepe'; -- this fails (the name of the transaction, what is the meaning, what is use for?)
 -- It complains about this "ERROR:  transaction identifier "pepe" is already in use"

insert into t2 (field) values ('another_value');

COMMIT PREPARED 'pepe'
```

As you may see I don't understand how to use two phase commits on Postgres.

### Summary

I'm not getting how to perform synchronization commands on different DB within the same RDBMS.

I have read [in the Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-prepare-transaction.html) that for synchronizing works across two or more unrelated Postgres databases an implementation of the so called "two-phases commits" protocol is at our disposal.

So I start trying to see how people do actually use them within the Postgres, I do not see any actual example, at most I get to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34799/postgresql-two-phase-commit-transaction-identifier) of a guy that was trying to experiment with several Postgres client connected to the different databases in order to emulate the multiple process running in paralell doing things to the several dbs that should end in a successful (all commit) or failure result (all rollback).

Other sources I have seen examples were:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol (this source
  explain well the protocol but really makes me wonder where or who is
  my "Coordinator" and how to send messages to the "participants"... i
  only got `prepare transaction <id>`, `commit prepared <id>` or
  `rollback prepared <id>` commands at my disposal)
- [Two phase commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389382/two-phase-commit)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145656/dependent-transaction-in-separate-database-connections
- https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/07/distributed-transactions-and-two-phase/
- https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2017/11/22/how-citus-executes-distributed-transactions/
- (From a golang client-app) https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/490

### Resolution (After Laurenz's Answer)

Connected to db1, these are the SQL lines to execute:

```
BEGIN;
-- DO THINGS TO BE DONE IN A ALL OR NOTHING FASHION
-- Stop point --    
PREPARE TRANSACTION 't1';
COMMIT PREPARED 't1' || ROLLBACK PREPARED 't1' (decision requires awareness and coordination)
```

Meanwhile connected to the db2 these will be the script to execute:

```
BEGIN;
-- DO THINGS TO BE DONE IN A ALL OR NOTHING FASHION
-- Stop point --  
PREPARE TRANSACTION 't2';

COMMIT PREPARED 't2' || ROLLBACK PREPARED 't2'
```

- The `-- Stop point --` is where a coordinator process (for example
  an application executing the statement, or a human behind a psql
  client console or pgAdminII) shall stop the execution of both
  scripts (actually not execute any further instruction, that is what I mean by stop).
- Then, first on db1 (and then on db2, or vice versa) the
  coordinator process (whatever been human or not) must run `PREPARE TRANSACTION` on each connection.

  - If one of then fails, then the coordinator must run  `ROLLBACK PREPARED`  on those database where the transaction was already prepared and  `ROLLBACK`  on the others.
  - If no one fails the coordinator must run COMMIT PREPARED on all involved databases, an operation that shall not fail ever (like existing the home when you are one step outside your house with all the things properly set to exit safely)

Comment: guess this can help me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953423/postgresql-prepare-transaction?rq=1, i spend a lot of hours looking by two-phase commits instead of prepare-transaction... :S

Comment: the above link has an example that is odd i guess, based on Laurenz answer it's not preparing two transactions, and is it using two databases...

Comment: Note that one of the articles you mention has moved here: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/07/distributed-transactions-and-two-phase/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you misunderstood `PREPARE TRANSACTION`.

That statement ends work on the transaction, that is, it should be issued *after* all the work is done. The idea is that `PREPARE TRANSACTION` does everything that could potentially fail during a commit except for the commit itself. That is to guarantee that a subsequent `COMMIT PREPARED` cannot fail.

The idea is that processing is as follows:

- Run `START TRANSACTION` on all database involved in the distributed transaction.
- Do all the work. If there are errors, `ROLLBACK` all transactions.
- Run `PREPARE TRANSACTION` on all databases. If that fails anywhere, run `ROLLBACK PREPARED` on those database where the transaction was already prepared and `ROLLBACK` on the others.
- Once `PREPARE TRANSACTION` has succeeded everywhere, run `COMMIT PREPARED` on all involved databases.

That way, you can guarantee “all or nothing” across several databases.

One important component here that I haven't mentioned is the *distributed transaction manager*. It is a piece of software that persistently memorizes where in the above algorithm processing currently is so that it can clean up or continue committing after a crash.

Without a distributed transaction manager, two-phase commit is not worth a lot, and it is actually dangerous: if transactions get stuck in the “prepared” phase but are not committed yet, they will continue to hold locks and (in the case of PostgreSQL) block autovacuum work *even through server restarts*, as such transactions must needs be persistent.

This is difficult to get right.

Comment: "I think you misunderstood PREPARE TRANSACTION" <-- totally true. Thanks for the answers Laurenz, i guess it helps me a lot. Talking about a transaction manager would only add layers of information that make the entire compression gets harder, so for a start lets stay focus on the simple scenario where there are no external failures have to be controlled by an overseer process. I will modify my example, following your explanation, and if you don't mind, you may validate it please. THanks again,

Comment: If you have no transaction manager, better not use distributed transactions.

Comment: Ok i got the idea, and i guess that the very application i use to connect to the databases could be the overseer process so called transaction manager, no? but, again.. let's go in baby steps here! We have an app programmed in Golang, we make our things agains the databases using that app.

Comment: Sure it can be. But then it had better make sure to persist the information so that it can resume working after a crash. Otherwise you end up with "stuck" prepared transactions.

Comment: Great Laurenz, and thanks again for all those tips and information, you really are helping me a lot!. I will get to the "transaction manager" thing.. but first i need how to write properly well the very very sql lines, i am modifying my example above, in order to display results!

Comment: Laurenz i have updated my question adding an example of two-phase commits usages. Can you validate it, please? If it's correct, then we can talk about where to get one of those "transaction manager" or how to implement they at a client-application level (client of the RDBMS i mean).

Comment: I think that would exceed the scope of a Stackoverflow answer.

Comment: i DO think that "transaction-manager" affairs can be addressed on a separated (but related) question (e.g. "how to implement a transaction manager for two-phase commits in postgres", for example)... but for now, can't you tell me if i understood? (i have updated my question adding important information)

Comment: Yes, looks like you got it right. Be warned that "How to write a distributed transaction manager?" is a question that is too broad. Try to get literature on the dubject.

Comment: Thanks again!! i'm taking note of that: "The two-phase commits are a great tool that comes full of perils and dangers", with a big label screaming "in production environments do not use without transaction manager".